# ColdFusion Implementing Strategy Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, coldfusion, strategy-pattern

I am new to ColdFusion and using ColdFusion MX (7) and I am interested in to implement Strategy Pattern. But I don't know what will be the best possible way to start the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a Google look up on ColdFusion Design Patterns and you'll find a couple of sites.

In the meantime hope this one helps (linked updated 04/01/2018) - https://web.archive.org/web/20150314004313/http://coldfusiondesignpatterns.org/strategy.html

Comment: Website has been updated, now URL is : 
http://coldfusiondesignpatterns.org/strategy.html

Comment: Both Zarko's and my original link are now dead so I've updated my answer with a Wayback archive site link to Zarko's.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend head [First Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1296121587&sr=8-2) book. It covers the strategy pattern as well as a bunch of others, it's well written and will help you again and again when designing applications.

Comment: +1 on the recommendation - great read to get your head around the  theory but it's aimed at Java Developers, not ColdFusion

Answer (score 0):

First identify your `Context` - that is the environment you want to execute a strategy within. If this relates to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805251/parameters-management-for-complete-website), I'd suggest Product Detail falls into this category and might be coded as such:

```
<cfcomponent name="ProductDetail">
  <cffunction name="getOverview" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="criteria"/>
    <!--- call strategy here --->
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Reason for this approach, instead of a class hierarchy with inheritance, is if the ProductDetail otherwise has behavior (i.e. functions) that are global to the problem.

The second step is identifying the various strategies, which appear to be related to Search Criteria. You may need to go through a mapping exercise between product and criteria strategy, particularly if the relationship between the two is many to many.